# JBoss Fuse Workspace Reference

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fabric8

I have created a JBoss Fuse Camel integration project and I can deploy it as a Profile on the Karaf Server using fabric8:deploy. The project is running fine so far.
Now I want to create a new Profile to do some other tasks. In oder to avoid double code, I wanted to create a Commons Project and add common code into this. But i cannot figure out how to add the dependency so that fabric8:deploy will still work and also deploy the commons library on BOTH profiles.

How should I add the commons project to both projects pom.xml?

I tried to add it as a normal dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but i'm getting this error when i want to deploy it via fabric8:deploy:

> The POM for com.my.project:common-tools:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available

and

> Failed to execute goal on project inbound: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my.project:inbound:bundle:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.my.project:common-tools:jar:1.0.0 in https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of red-hat-ga-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that your common-tools project could not be found in the maven repositories.  Do you have it in your local maven repo?  Have you done a:

```
mvn clean install
```

for the common-tools project?

Comment: The common-tools is complied and is available in the repo. But it does not get deployed on the fabric, if i run fabric8:deploy